# How to get the zipballUrl of a branch using github graphQL API?

Tags: github, github-graphql, github-api-v4

I am trying to programmatically download a zip file of a repository which is already checked out to a specific branch. 
For that I need to obtain the zipballUrl of the head of the branch I specify through [github graphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47478877/3236818) specifies how to get the zipballUrl of the default branch but I could not alter it to my requirement. Appreciate if someone can help out.

PS: Running a git clone command and checking out to branch is not an option because the programming language I use (ballerina) does not support shell commands yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reference field of the repository object.

For example, considering the same google gson project

```
{
  repository(owner: "google", name: "gson") {

    ref(qualifiedName: "722"){
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          tarballUrl
          zipballUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this query ref(qualifiedName) will basically look for the reference or branch name with the specified value and return the tar content of the branch.

Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "ref": {
        "target": {
          "tarballUrl": "https://codeload.github.com/google/gson/legacy.tar.gz/2725be440147a71030ece93683b4424e849c59ed",
          "zipballUrl": "https://codeload.github.com/google/gson/legacy.zip/2725be440147a71030ece93683b4424e849c59ed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can verify the sha of the branch reference "722"
https://github.com/google/gson/commit/2725be440147a71030ece93683b4424e849c59ed

Comment: Thank you very much !!!. To avoid any confusion for a fellow reader, "722" is the name of a branch in google gson repo though it may look odd.